# Prevent FormFieldText reset after calling camera activity in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-provider

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
            controller: textController,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap : () async {
                 await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
              },
              child: Center(
                child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt, size:50),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

i m loosing text entered in textfield after cameractivity.....
plz guide me in this regards.
thanx in advance.

below is flutter doctor -v output...
**
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.239], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.8 at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision 0b8abb4724 (6 weeks ago), 2020-02-11 11:44:36 -0800
    • Engine revision e1e6ced81d
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\sonu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\sonu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 39.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 183.6270
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.43.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\sonu\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.8.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Redmi Y2 • 12c7f04 • android-arm • Android 9 (API 28)

• No issues found!
**
Screenshot....

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
onTap: () async {
  FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
  await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

solved.

acctually its version issue...

i was using stable v1.12.13+hotfix.8, its working fine with dev channel.